# Find background-image url that is empty

Tags: jquery, background-image, inline-styles

Working in a CMS and trying to target the divs that have a style attribute background-image: url() (background image has no url) so I can add a class to the div with no url and style in CSS. I've been unsuccessful at my attempts.

Here is the html output:

```
<article class="feeds-post" style="background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ELuUkHpVAAEe9yn.jpg)"></article>

<article class="feeds-post" style="background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ELuMTeUUYAAn_Pc.jpg)"></article>

<article class="feeds-post" style="background-image: url()"></article>
```

```
$('.parentDiv article').each(function(){
  if ($(this).css('background-image', 'url()')) {
   $(this).addClass('noimage');
  };
});
```

The above code targets all of the divs, even the ones that do have a background image. How do I target the background-image without the url?